# Are Jenkins job templates only accessible downtree from the folder of their definition?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

It appears that our Jenkins job templates are only accessible downtree from the folder in which they're created. This means that if we want a universally available template, it must be created in the Jenkins root directory which of course potentially floods up on Jenkins root. Any way to expose a Jenkins job template outside the folder it's in?

Comment: Both the [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) and the [jobtemplates Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/jobtemplates+Plugin) use other projects as templates, not files in Jenkin's directory structure. What are you referring to when you talk about „_Jenkins job templates_“?

Comment: I was referring to [CloudBees Template Plugin](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/template.html#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as [documented](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/template-sect-in-folders.html) a template can only be used in or beneath the folder in which it is defined.

There is an RFE CJP-1525 in the internal tracker suggesting that as an alternative, a designated subfolder (like the 3.x `Templates/`) of the common root folder also be searched. (The extension point to allow this from an outside plugin already exists.)

Answer (score 0):

See the last sentence of the section [*Using the Folders plugin*](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/folder-sect-usage.html#folder-sect-template) of the documentation you linked in the comments:

> **Templates Plugin**
>
> You can place a template inside a folder rather than at top level. Then the template is only offered to jobs (or other templates) in that folder or below.